# Splitting values in an array 'logarithmically' / based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array, where each element is a fourier transform. I'd like to split transform 'logarithmically'. For example, let's take a single one of those arrays and call it `a`:

```
a = np.arange(0, 512)

# I want to split a into 'bins' defined by b, below:
b = np.array([0] + [10 * 2**i for i in range(6)]) # [0, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640]
```

What I'm looking to do is something like using `np.split`, except I would like to split values into 'bins' based on array `b` such that all values of `a` between [0, 10) are in one bin, all values between [10, 20) in another, etc.

I could do this in some sort of convoluted for loop:

```
split_arr = []
for i in range(1, len(b)):
    fbin = []
    for amp in a:
        if (amp >= b[i-1]) and (amp < b[i]):
            fbin.append(amp)
    split_arr.append(fbin)
```

I have many arrays to split, and also this is ugly (just my opinion). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, using `np.split`:

```
np.split(a, np.searchsorted(a,b))
```

If your array `a` is not sorted, sort it before the above command:

```
a = np.sort(a)
```

`np.searchsorted` finds the locations of values in `b` that would be inserted in the sorted array `a`. In other words, `np.searchsorted` finds the locations where you want to split your array. And if you do not want the empty array at the beginning, simply remove `0` from `b`.

Comment: Just timed this. Blazing fast and so concise. I'm glad I waited a few minutes to check out answers. I'm looking up `np.searchsorted` in the docs now, as I'd like to understand it more. Thank you.

Comment: @rocksNwaves You are welcome. I added another line for more explanation. Hope it helps. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: So this probably assumes a is sorted in the first place... which is why it's so fast. If `a` is not sorted then you need to factor in the cost of sorting it. Still probably the most efficient method, especially for big arrays.

Comment: @Julien Yes, Thank you for the note. Added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

First you can reduce the 'ugliness' by using list comprehension:

```
split_arr = [[amp for amp in a if (amp >= b[i-1]) and (amp < b[i])] for i in range(1, len(b))]
```

Then you can apply the same logic using numpy fast parallelized functionalities (which has the bonus of looking even cleaner):

```
split_arr = [a[(a >= b[i-1]) & (a < b[i])] for i in range(1, len(b))]
```

Comparison:

```
%timeit [[amp for amp in a if (amp >= b[i-1]) and (amp < b[i])] for i in range(1, len(b))]
1.29 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [a[(a >= b[i-1]) & (a < b[i])] for i in range(1, len(b))]
35.9 µs ± 4.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I would really love to know the reason of the downvote...